# C# Ghostscript/Ghostview wrong papersize/margins

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript and Ghostgum to print a PDF. My PDF is a POS receipt, so it has the dimensions of 80cm x unlimited Y.

What happens is that in Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, Chrome or Firefox prints perfectly if I disabled some options such as:

[image]

But in Ghostview it seems it does not have that option, and when I try to print both width and height are incorrect. Besides it creates a large margin on header, and dunno why.

I have tried different command lines without success.

```
printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-noquery -portrait -dPDFFitPage -printer \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", this.__PRINTER, this.__PATH_TO_SAVE + filename);
```

I also open the GSView application and printed directly from there and the issue remains.
[image]

The only reason I'm using both of this applications (GSView and GSScript) is to print silently (without opening any window), thing that Adobe Reader or Foxit do not allow.

Comment: I am having the same issue with ghostscript when attempting to print a receipt (same dimensions).  Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't solve. I end up using Foxit.

Comment: No worries, I ended up printing directly using PrintDocument instead of creating a pdf.